# Generating randomised coordinates data set using R?

Tags: r, coordinates, random

I am looking to produce a data set of randomised coordinates points that can easily be generated in R with something like:

```
Seqlat <- seq(from=-90, to=90, by=.01)
Seqlong <- seq(from=-180, to=180, by=.01)
Latitude <- sample(Seqlat, size=1000, replace=TRUE)
Longitude <- sample(Seqlong, size=1000, replace=TRUE)
VirtualCoordinates <- data.frame(x= Longitude, y = Latitude)
```

but instead of completely random coordinates, I am looking for all my coordinates to only be over land.

I can visualise and detect which points occur on land with ggplot2:

```
WorldData <- map_data('world') 
Vcoordinates_map <- ggplot() +
                     geom_map(data = WorldData, map = WorldData,
                      aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, map_id=region),
                       fill = "white", colour = "#7f7f7f", size=0.5) + 
                        coord_equal()+
                         theme_bw() +
stat_binhex(data=VirtualCoordinates, 
             bins = 100, colour = "black", 
              aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude))


Vcoordinates_map
```

But I not sure how to set "land" as a condition or an if statement, when generating the data set.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181586/remove-points-which-are-out-of-shapefile-or-raster-extent)? I think it is relevant to your case.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104908/random-geographic-coordinates-on-land-avoid-ocean) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990148/how-to-add-random-markers-to-a-map-but-avoiding-the-sea) are useful. Have a look.